# g:each iterator value not being applied in name of input

Tags: grails, each

So I've got a basic, g:each like so: -

```
<g:each in="${results}" status = "i" var="item">
            <tr id = ${i} class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}" name="main">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table id = "sub">
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Action</b></td><td>
                            <g:select  style="width:375px;"name="events[$i].id" from="${framework.EventType.list(sort:"userEventType")}" required="required" optionKey="id" value="${item.event_id}" /></td>
                            <td><b>Object</b></td>
                            <td>


                            <input type="text" name="any[$i].id">
                            <g:select style="width:550px;"id="objectID[$i]" name="objectID[$i].id" from="${framework.Object.list(sort:"objDesc")}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${item.object_id}" class="many-to-one"/>

                            <richui:autoComplete name="autocomp[$i].id" value= "${item.object_description}" action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'object/searchAJAX')}" maxResultsDisplayed="20" minQueryLength ="3" onItemSelect="youPickedThis(id,'autocomp[$i].id')" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                                
                </td>   
            </tr>
        </g:each>
```

Absolutely everything within here is generated in the html with the correct names (i.e. [$i] becomes [0] on the first each, [1] on the second and so on.  But the very first input (type text) just names them all "any[$i].id"!

Anyone have the remotest idea why the first input is too good to pick up up whereas the other elements just get on with it as they should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I can see is that the `<input type="text">` is a plain HTML tag whereas all the other places where you're using `$i` are attributes of GSP tags (`richui:autocomplete` and `g:select`).  Try using `${i}` instead:

```
<input type="text" name="any[${i}].id">
```

I wasn't aware that the short form (without using braces) was valid *anywhere* in a GSP, but the longer brace form will definitely work in all cases.

Comment: I could kiss you.  Cheers!